# The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have tried a piece of sql query somewhere else to fetch value from XML string and it works, but when I tried to implement it somewhere else in an **almost** similar situation I am getting this error:

The argument 1 of the XML data type method nodes must be a string literal

My query is like this:

```
        Select * into #ContentItemsOnStaging from ( SELECT A.id as
        NodeID,A.text as NodeName,B.text as Parent , A.createDate as
        DateCreated ,
-- Problem is from here
        ( SELECT pref.value('(/' + E.alias
        +'/@updateDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS LastUpdatedDate FROM   
(SELECT  CAST(xml AS xml) AS XmlCol FROM [ContentXml] WHERE nodeId = A.id )  
AS XmlStuff CROSS APPLY XmlCol.nodes('/' + E.alias) AS x(pref) ) 
-- To Here
        FROM [Node] as A left join Node B on A.parentID = B.id left join [ContentXml] as C on 
    A.id = C.nodeId  left join [Content] as D on A.id = D.nodeId  left join [cmsContentType] 
    as E on D.contentType = E.nodeId) as test2
```

The problem is from E.Alias. 
What I need is sending a customizable Header to be searched for. Is there any workarounds for that?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to bind relational data from `cmsContentType.Alias` to xml element names. The reason for the error is you are constructing the xquery path via string concatenation which is not going to work.

To reference the column from your xquery you need to use the `sql:column()` function.  A simple example is below, and [more info here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx).

```
declare @tab table (Alias varchar(100));
insert into @tab
    select 'one' union all
    select 'two'


declare @x xml;
set @x = '<root><one updateDate="01-01-2014" /><two updateDate="01-01-2013" /></root>';

select  Alias,
        @x.value('(//*[local-name(.)=sql:column("t.Alias")])[1]/@updateDate', 'datetime')
from    @tab t;
```

This will get you the first element beneath `<root>` which joins to your `Alias` value, then it retrieves an attribute value (`updateDate`).

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: The problem is the xml string is not always starting with specific tag (root) in your case. the header is depends on the documentType. And that's why I am trying to pass E.alias.

Comment: @amirmoradifard see update, now without leading root path. A double slash `//` will search the entire document, which isnt great but might be your only option if you dont have a known xpath

Comment: +1 by sql:column("alias").. looks great, now I'm thinking how explore full xml schema working dynamically over nodes :)